# Medium for Pseudomonas?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, experimental-design, medium

What is a good minimal medium for *Pseudomonas* bacteria? Do I need different media for different *Pseudomonas* species?

Answer (score 6):

*Pseudomonas* bacteria are generally not difficult to grow:

> Rugged and opportunistic, *Pseudomonas* use a wide range of nutritional sources, even very simple nutritional environments without any organic compounds. - [Sigma](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/analytix/pseudomonas-media.html)

For specific species, you'll want to use a selection medium. Sigma-Aldrich has a number of  [commercial products](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/analytix/pseudomonas-media.html) for selection and I'm sure you can find a recipe that suits your species with a Google search.

---

Related reading:

[Medium for the Selective Isolation of Members of the Genus Pseudomonas from Natural Habitats](http://aem.asm.org/content/33/5/1222.full.pdf) (Grant and Holt, 1977)

[Evaluation of various selective media for the detection of Pseudomonas species in pasteurized milk](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22365238) (Van Tassell *et al.*, 2012)